# Vue.js + Disable select dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the below dropdown which is disabled based on certain condition. However even in disabled mode it is clickable and when clicked it shows a blue border around it. How can i remove the blue border around it when its in disabled state

Below is the code -

```
<li>
    <select 
      v-bind:disabled="disableFilter" 
      v-model="currentFilter" 
      :title="filterName" 
      @change="changeDropdwnFilter($event)">
          <option value="*">Show All Columns</option>
          <option 
              v-for="item in filters" 
              :title="item.ice_name" 
              :value="item.id">
                  {{ item.name }}
          </option>
    </select>
</li>
```

left image : Disabled Dropdown

Right image : when clicked on disabled dropdown

[image]

Comment: I think the blue line is a `outline`, but it shouldn't show it if it's disabled, could you produce the issue, on a stackoverflow code snippet or any live editor like codesandbox?

Comment: Blue border should not show for the disabled field. Here is the demo link https://jsfiddle.net/hkn8w65g/ .. please have a look and try to find the root cause by comparing with your code.

Comment: I had this applied to on all dropdown on the page and that is why the blue outline was showing. Thank you for responding
 select:active {
            border-color: rgb(0, 120, 212);
        }